# Questions Number 8 and 9 from College Algebra CLEP Study Guide

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Needing help with some more questions on my College Algebra Clep Study Guide. :/

I'm not looking for answers. I'm just looking to know how to solve some questions.

Can anyone please help?

http://puu.sh/anN5Q/bf71ac4cc5.png

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and what is confusing you. It will help us give you better answers.

Comment: I wanted to see someone do the two math problems because I learn quick when I see full examples.

Comment: For the first you need to remember what $n!$ means. Then you will see that $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=n+1$. For the second you just need to gather all the $t$s together and all the $r$s together, then apply the laws of indices.

Comment: You guys helped me understand these concepts. I didn't even have to provide my attempts and I still was helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(8) $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}-n = \frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)\cdots(2)(1)}{n(n-1)\cdots(2)(1)}-n = (n+1)-n = 1$.

(9) $r^2t^{1/2}r^{2/3}t^{-3/2} = r^2r^{2/3}t^{1/2}t^{-3/2} = r^{2+2/3}t^{1/2-3/2} = r^{8/3}t^{-1} = \frac{r^{8/3}}{t}$.

Comment: How did you get r^8/3 from r^2+2/3?

Comment: Where did (n)(n-1) come from?

Comment: It sounds to me as though you need to go back and do some basic studying. The denominator $n(n-1)\cdots(2)(1)$ is just the expansion of $n!$ (the product of integers from $n$ down to $1$. And since $\frac{8}{3} = 2+\frac{2}{3}$, the laws of exponents tell us that $r^{2+2/3} = r^{8/3}$.